# Laravel run artisan command continuously

Tags: laravel

What I'd like to do is run an artisan command continuously on a server. I'm aware of cronjobs and scheduling in Laravel, but that wouldn't work as the processing involves making calls to APIs and sometimes takes 1 second, and sometimes 15. So I'd like to run it continuously.

I've found several pieces to this puzzle but can't quite put it together.

Let's say I have this in my custom artisan artisan command:

```
public function handle()
{
  $this->info('Test');
}
```

If I now run `nohup php artisan customcommand` I get `appending output to nohup.out`. The file nohup.out only has 'Test' once. So it does not seem it is running the `handle()` function continuously?

Now if I do this and run it with `nohup`:

```
public function handle()
{
    $i = 1;
    while(true)
    {
        $this->info('Test '.$i);
        sleep(5);
        $i++;
    }
}
```

It does run continuously and I get `Test 1, Test 2, etc` in `nohup.out`. Using the `while(true)` loop feels hacky though. Is this the right way to do it?

Eventually, `$this->info('Test');` will be replaced by a controller function that should run continuously but wanted to make sure I get the basics right.

**Update**

If I do the below I get a `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)` so instantiating a new controller in the while loop does not seem like a good idea?

```
public function handle()
{
    while(true)
    {
        $controller = new MyController;
        $controller->index();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As i can read from your post, it seems you want to run the call, and then straight after run the next, and so on. rather than schedueling it to run like every minute, or every second.

What you currently do, is you make a new instance of the MyController every time you go through the loop.

so to fix this you could move it out of the loop

```
public function handle()
{
    $controller = new MyController;

    while(true)
    {
        $controller->index();
    }

}
```

What you want to make sure, is not to continue creating something new every time you run through the loop.